# invalid workspace configuration: case mismatch in path in golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

After installing golang using homebrew I am getting this see below screenshot error in my vscode and IntelliSense is not working as well.
I have no idea how to resolve this any help would be great.

FYI : I did install all the extension recommended for golang in vscode .

[image: vscode image]

vs code

> Settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
    },
    "cSpell.userWords": [
        "Aditya",
        "Bluespacelabs",
        "Formik",
        "Highcharts",
        "Kumar",
        "Palin",
        "semibold"
    ],
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
            80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "gitlens.advanced.messages": {
        "suppressImproperWorkspaceCasingWarning": true
    },
    "editor.tabSize": 8,
    "editor.cursorStyle": "line",
    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.lineNumbers": "on",
    "editor.wordSeparators": "/\\()\"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`?-",
    "editor.wordWrap": "off",
    "diffEditor.wordWrap": "on",
    "json.schemas": [
        {
            "name": "vscode-expo-manifest",
            "url": "file:///Users/adityakumar/Library/Application%20Support/Code/User/globalStorage/bycedric.vscode-expo/manifest-42.0.0.json",
            "fileMatch": [
                "app.json",
                "app.config.json"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your vscode settings, and how you opened the folder? It looks like vscode uses a file path that includes 'desktop' (lowercase) but gopls thinks it should start with 'Desktop'. It's unclear why vscode believes sent lower case 'desktop'. Are you using a workspace setting and specifying the workspace root file path using the lowercase 'desktop' by any chance?

Comment: fyi filed https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47509 to improve the error message.

Comment: @Hana I have added my complete settings.JSON in question

Comment: this error is really frustrating i really want to solve this.

Comment: path of my project `/Users/adityakumar/desktop/pluralsight-go/getting-started/code`

Comment: Change your project path to be `"/Users/adityakumar/Desktop/pluralsight-go/getting-started/code"` (See the change from "desktop" to "Desktop").

The file system (probably mac) is case-insensitive, but most go toolings are case sensitive.

Comment: I reinstalled the vscode after uninstalling it now it seems to be working.